# Seeking Advice on Python Mathematical Loop

Tags: python, numpy, math, python-requests

I am using python to calculate the forward, central, and backward finite differences of f(x)=cos(x). I can get them to plot when it is running each iteration at a set step size (h). However, my main task is to have the step size be reduced by a factor of two for each iteration of the finite difference methods. Here is the loop I tried to do but it did not work.

```
h = 5
while h > 0.0005:
    h = h / 2
```

And this is my code where it has the constant step size that I am trying to change to where it reduces by a factor of 2 for each iteration.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x: np.cos(x)

h=5

#Forward Difference
dff1=(f(x+h)-f(x))/h
plt.plot(x,dff1,'-b')


#Backward Difference
dff1=(f(x)-f(x-h))/h
plt.plot(x,dff1,'-r')


#Central Difference
dff1=(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h)
plt.plot(x,dff1,'-g')

#plot
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(["FFD","BFD","CFD"])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I'm still new to coding so please don't judge me too hard if this is an easy problem! I appreciate any help or advice that can be offered!!! :)

Comment: That loop will plainly produce a small enough `h`, but only that *one* value for consumption by whatever code **after** the loop.  Did you mean to put something else *in* the loop so as to use each reduced value in succession?  (Also, where is `x` defined?)

Comment: Yes, I want to have all of the h values on one plot starting with the largest (5) and being divided by 2 until it ends at my smallest h value (whatever the number is closest to 0.0005). Basically this will show how the equation becomes more accurate as the h is reduced. Do you think you could help me with that? I hope I made myself more clear!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you plotted the figure (used h) **inside the while loop's body**, what you said should work.

In more detail:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x: np.cos(x)

x=np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=50)    #x should be initialized. this line was missing.

h=5
while h > 0.0005:
   h = h/2.               #starts at 5/2 for the first iteration. 5/4 for the second,..etc
   #Forward Difference
   dff1=(f(x+h)-f(x))/h
   plt.plot(x,dff1,'-b')


   #Backward Difference
   dff1=(f(x)-f(x-h))/h
   plt.plot(x,dff1,'-r')


   #Central Difference
   dff1=(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h)
   plt.plot(x,dff1,'-g')

   #plot
   plt.xlabel('x')
   plt.ylabel('y')
   plt.legend(["FFD","BFD","CFD"])
   plt.grid()
   plt.show()                 #the next iteration won't start until you close the window.
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. How do I get it where it will put all of my h values on the plot.? Right now it is only using what I set h equal to when I made the changes you had.

Comment: It essentially will if you move the last line that displays the image outside the while loop. (Simply unindent it.) It works because this makes it loop and plot on the same figure each iteration so we only need to display the figure after the loop ends.